# Como receber valor por GET?

Tags: php, ajax, aplicação-web, get

ola pessoal estou desenvolvendo um trabalho e preciso pegar um valor por get na url mas não estou conseguindo se alguem poder me ajudar e mostrar meu erro agradeço:

```
<?php require_once("../database/conexao.php") ?>
<?php 

url = teste.com/teste.php?q=123456
if( isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST) ) {
   $cpf = $_GET["q"];
   $npass = $_POST["newpass1"]; 
   $newpass  = "UPDATE usuarios ";
   $newpass .= "SET ";
   $newpass .= "senha = '{$npass}' ";
   $newpass .= "WHERE cpf = '$cpf'";  
   $confirma =  mysqli_query($conecta,$newpass);

   if($confirma){
      echo $cpf;
      echo "senha alterada com sucesso";
   }else{
      echo "problemas ao alterar senha";
   }
}

?>
```

eu coloco um echo na minha variável `$cpf` e ela não aparece nada

Comment: Mas aparece a mensagem `"senha alterada com sucesso"`?

Comment: Seu script somente vai executar se tiver algum $_post. Então se nada for não executa. Outra coisa é que a variável $confirma é verificada se é verdadeira. Talvez sua requisição no banco não é executada por estar dando erro. Nesta parte where cpf = ‘$cpf’ se cpf for um número inteiro de 11 dígitos sem os pontos vai passar, se não for tem que colocar dentro de colchetes. Outra coisa é que se não tiver o cpf no banco que quer mudar pode retorna false.

Comment: ola amigo obrigado pela respota, é essa é so a parte do codigo ele esta interagindo com uma html e quando eu dou o post atraves de uma botao submit aparece a mensagem senha alterada com sucesso porem no banco continua a anteiror e como eu disse quando peço pra ele me mostrar o get com um echo não aparece valor nenhum. isso é pra ser m metodo de redefinição de senha por link